# How to use ngSwitch on datatype in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, instanceof, typeof, ng-switch

I was working in angular2 and was curious to know whether I could use ngSwitch to load `<div>` tag when variable is of certain datatype.i.e.
something like this:

```
 <div [ng-switch]="value">
  <p *ng-switch-when="isObject(value)">This is Object</p>
  <p *ng-switch-when="isArray(value)">This is Array</p>
  <p *ng-switch-when="isBoolean(value)">This is Boolean</p>
  <p *ng-switch-when="isNumber(value)">This is Number</p>
  <p *ng-switch-default>This is Simple Text !</p>
</div>
```

is this possible to load the `div` tag when variable is of certain datatype?
if not, any workaround for this?

Comment: why don't you use ngIf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative would be to use `ngIf`:

```
  <p *ngIf="isObject(value)">This is Object</p>
  <p *ngIf="isArray(value)">This is Array</p>
  <p *ngIf="isBoolean(value)">This is Boolean</p>
  <p *ngIf="isNumber(value)">This is Number</p>
  <p *ngIf="!isObject(value) || !isArray(value) || !isBoolean(value) || !isNumber(value)">This is Simple Text !</p>
```

Comment: so ngIf responds on the first false it finds ? interesting. || will evaluate each  of the statements looking for a true normally wont it ? meaning that code should output a mess.

Comment: The other way around, it shows all the `p` tags that evaluate to `true` values

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it but now directly in template. Just create a method in controller to check for a type:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <div [ngSwitch]="checkType(name)">
        <p *ngSwitchCase="'string'">is a string!</p>
        <p *ngSwitchDefault>default</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'
  }

  checkType(value) {
    return typeof value
  }
}
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JIeLEzxSIepwXtOSppSs?p=preview)

---

Please update your Angular to RC version first.