# Ngswitch: show elements when typeof 'rating' is a number

Tags: javascript, angular

I got a question. I want to show certain html elements when the typeof my 'rating' property in my component is a number. Otherwise I want it to show other elements. I tried the following:

```
<div class="col">
    <div [ngSwitch]="rating">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="null" ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle>Rate The Movie!</button>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                <button value="1" (click)="addRating(1)" class="dropdown-item">1</button>
                <button value="2" (click)="addRating(2)" class="dropdown-item">2</button>
                <button value="3" (click)="addRating(3)" class="dropdown-item">3</button>
                <button value="4" (click)="addRating(4)" class="dropdown-item">4</button>
                <button value="5" (click)="addRating(5)" class="dropdown-item">5</button>
            </div>
            </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="typeof === number">
                    <h1>{{rating}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Unfortunately

> *ngSwitchCase="typeof === number"

doesn't work. Does someone know how to do this? I am aware that I could use ngIf, but in a later state I would like to add more options, so that's why I picked ngswitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ngSwitch is a good candidate in your scenario.

Why don't you use ngIf?

```
<div *ngIf="rating === null" ...>
//...
<div *ngIf="rating !== null && typeof rating === 'number'">
```

If you really want to use ngSwitch, anf you only have 2 cases (null or number), then use ngSwitchDefault to handle the number case. But a ngIf is cleaner imho

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token === at column 34 in [rating !== null && typeof rating === 'number'] in ng:///AppModule/MovieComponent.html@21:29

Comment: I followed the advice of a comment below and just entered 'number' instead typeof rating === 'number' and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof`  is an operator which needs to be passed 'something' to check the type of. It also provides the answer as a string. So you probably want:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="typeof rating === 'number'">
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: compiler.js?7e34:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token === at column 15 in [typeof rating === 'number'] in ng:///AppModule/MovieComponent.html@22:29 ("

Comment: OK - Looking deeper into this, it looks like you probably can't use typeof in this way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013862/use-ngswitch-on-datatype-in-angular2 for some alternative ideas.